# Which import to use with FontAwesomeIcon, React and Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome, jestjs

I have a React site (using TypeScript & Webpack) that uses FortAwesome's `react-fontawesome` package to render icons. This package is imported as follows:

```
import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
```

While adding Jest tests using Enzyme, any tests that use a component containing a reference to `FontAwesomeIcon` fail with the following:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in
components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. 
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might
have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Changing the import on those components to:

```
import * as FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
```

fixes the test, but then browsing to a page containing that component fails with:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in
components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

I expect this is a conflict between ES6, Babel and perhaps the phase of the moon, but after several hours of fighting this I'm out of ideas...

Comment: Do you use external loading or explicit/custom library import (import icon,-s you need)?

Comment: The icons themselves are imported as objects, e.g. `import * as faUser from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-solid/faUser';`, `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} />`

Answer (score 1):

As expected this was a clash of standards, and more related to TypeScript than anything else. The solution was to add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` to the `tsconfig.json` file. Hopefully this helps those who come after...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use
`import * as FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';`
then you have to use:
`<FontAwesomeIcon.default icon={faUser} />`
(=you pick up the function/react-component)

`import *` converts non-objects to objects and adds `.default` property which points to original module type (function in our case). Every component you import/use to create a new react component should be a function, class or tag-string (e.g.`<div>`) and not an object and this is the reason you got the `type is invalid` error. [React.createElement() docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)

Check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lxj5mwmw5z) to see a working example of fontawesome with `import * as`.
Note the difference between "imports" logged at the console of the sandbox

I tested also locally your case with create-react-app and didn't have any issues to jest or react.

EDIT: Both errors you got are related with react (not typescript or jest).

Comment: Thanks @AndreasT, unfortunately while that change would keep the site running, the Jest tests still fail with the same error, which makes sense if `import FontAwesomeIcon...` & `<FontAwesomeIcon.../>` and `import * as FontAwesomeIcon...` & `<FontAwesomeIcon.default.../>` are equivalent.